# fluent ui tooltip in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, fluentui-react

Hello I am new to using fluent ui and applying it to my react.

I am trying to align my tooltip with my textfield and trying to change background color to black and font to white. Also increasing the width and height of tooltipbox.

[image]

```
     const inlineBlockStyle = (styleProps) => {
    
            const chkStyles = {
    
                root: [{
    
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    color: 'white',
                    backgroundColor: black,
                    height: '100px',
                    width: '500px,'
                }],
    
            };
    
            return chkStyles
        };


   <TooltipHost
       content="If your school is not on our list, please go to the Support Page 
       and provide your schools details.  
    
       id={tooltip2Id}                                        
       calloutProps={calloutProps}
       styles={inlineBlockStyle}
    >

      <Label style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "20px" }}>  
        Please select your county and your school
         <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Info" </i>
      </Label>

   </TooltipHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const styleProps= {
  rootHovered: {
    backgroundColor: "black"
  }
};
//
<FluentPrimaryButton text = {label} styles = {styleProps} />;
```

Comment: I added more code and what tooltip im using

Comment: apparently not,  I am using <TooltipHost> not a <FluentPrimaryButton> I added what field i am using for tooltip

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/tooltip